# Sending " (quote marks) sign over cURL with JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm sending an array with data over cURL to another server (with PHP). Code before sending to prepare data:

```
$array['fieldA'] = urlencode('Something "special" here');
$array['fieldB'] = urlencode('text & number\'s content');
$data = json_encode($array);
// {"fieldA":"Something+%22special%22+here","fieldB":"text+%26+number%27s+content"}
```

and sending with CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "params=".$data);
```

Code on the other side

```
$data = json_decode($_POST, true);
$data['fieldA'] = urldecode($data['fieldA']);
$data['fieldB'] = urldecode($data['fieldB']);
```

var_dump of $_POST is different:

```
"{"fieldA":"Something "special" here","fieldB":"text & number's content"}"
```

And because there there is " (quote marks) it is not right JSON structure anymore.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your operations is wrong. You should use `urlencode()` as the very last operation, right before you send it with cURL as `json_encode()` will add characters that are not valid in a url:

```
$array['fieldA'] = 'Something "special" here';
$array['fieldB'] = 'text & number\'s content';
$data = urlencode(json_encode($array));
```